# Typescript - Get type of property, compile time

Tags: typescript

I sometimes just like to copy the type of a property, instead of using the property's type directly.  This might be because the type is declared inline, or because I expect it to change.  The property is on an interface that's part of a namespace.

I have tried:

```js
type IIdentity = Contracts.ICustomer.identities[number]
```

But that claims ICustomer is not a member of the Contracts namespace, which is somewhat misleading.

I have also tried a number of typeof combinations, all without results.

The only way I have come up with that works, is through a dummy function and the excellent new ReturnValue function, but this seems overly complex:

```js
const evilDummy = (x: Contracts.ICustomer) => x.identities[0]
type IIdentity = ReturnType<typeof evilDummy>
```

Anyone got a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use type queries:

```
interface ICustomer{ identities: boolean[] }
type IIdentity = ICustomer['identities'][number] // will be boolean
```

**Edit**

Or if the interface is in a namespace

```
namespace Contracts {
    export interface ICustomer{ identities: boolean[] }
}
type IIdentity = Contracts.ICustomer['identities'][number] // will be boolean
```

Comment: You are right, this worked - even with the namespace.  I tried this, but with the interface in brackets. That did not compute.

Comment: @JørgenTvedt yeah, the example was without namespaces. I will add a version with namespaces for others :)

Comment: Cool, this also works with keyof: ```const identityListIdField: keyof DataSchema.ICustomer['identities'][number] = "id"```